# Connection to AWS timed out using Python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cygwin, boto

I ran Python program in Cygwin to connect to AWS, but failed consistently as being timed out. But my connection to AWS using aws cli in Cygwin always works. Also if I run the same python code in Windows, it also works. I have checked all the connection credentials which are the same for all.

Here is the error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 585, in get_all_instances
    max_results=max_results)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 681, in get_all_reservations
    [('item', Reservation)], verb='POST')   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1170, in get_list 
    response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1116, in make_request
    return self._mexe(http_request)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex   
socket.error: [Errno 116] Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found out that the culprit lies in the proxy credentials.

I put `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` as Windows Environment Variables. However, when run in Cygwin, boto uses 'http_proxy' to match without considering the case of the word

```
(see  /boto/connection.py(669)handle_proxy()
line 669:  if 'http_proxy' in os.environ and not self.proxy:).
```

When I changed the capital case `HTTP_PROXY` to lower case `http_proxy`, then it worked. Not sure why it isn't a problem if I run with Python in Windows.